# Send JSON to restful API via Logic App and Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have JSON file which is composed in Logic Apps, Now i need to send this JSON file  to a Rest API using the Post method through Azure Function. 
Does anyone know how to achieve this using PowerShell in Function if not any other languages like c# or python?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to upload the file to a blob storage and generate a SAS url. Then you can use azure function to call the http and send the url.

```
 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            List<FileAndUrl> filenamesAndUrls;
            if (req.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
            {
                filenamesAndUrls = req.RequestUri.Query
                    .Remove(0, 1) // remove '?' at the start of the query
                    .Split('&') // all comands are seperated by '&'
                    .Select(s =>
                    {
                        var keyValue = s.Split('=');
                        return new FileAndUrl() { FileName = keyValue[0], Url = keyValue[1] };
                    }).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                filenamesAndUrls = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<FileAndUrl>>();
            }
            return CreateResult(filenamesAndUrls);
        }
```

[EXAMPLE](https://github.com/paule96/AzureFunctionDownloader/blob/master/Downloader/Downloader.cs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure functions connector in your workflow (logic apps). Then, you just need to set the body of the request with your payload, also specify the header 'Content-Type' as 'application/json'

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions